# Recursion on nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nested-lists

I am trying to use recursion on a nested list. Here I am trying to get the innermost element.

```
input_list = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7,[8,9,[10]]]]

list1 = input_list

def sublist1(list, sublist=[]):
    if len(list) == 0: 
        return sublist
    else: 
        sublist.append(list)
        sublist1(list[1:], sublist)
    
        print(sublist)

sublist1(list1)
```

The output I am getting is this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]], [2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]], [3, 4, [5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]], [4, [5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]], [[5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]]]
```

I tried changing the index but it's not giving me the expected output [10].
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why guard condition is `if len(list) == 0`? If you want the inner element then you should return when then length is 1. Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: I don't understand why you are appending the sublist to the existing list?

Comment: There could be more than one 'innermost' element in a structure like that, consider `input_list=[[1,2],[3,4]]`. You should clarify how to handle a case like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will answer your nested travels

```
input_list = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7,[8,9,[10]]]]

list1 = input_list

def sublist1(list):
    if(len(list) > 1):
        for l in list:
            #print(l)
           # print(type(l))
            if type(l) == type([]) :
               return sublist1(l)
            else:
                continue
    
    return list        
        


print(sublist1(list1))
```

Comment: I can see where I made mistake in logic. Thank you !!

Comment: Why do you not avoid overriding the built-in `list` function, but instead use a convoluted `type([])` to obtain the original `list`?

Comment: there is no need to check inheritance of list type so make it simple.

Comment: That isn't my point. My point is that you override the built-in `list` with a local variable even though you still need the built-in `list`, which you then need to obtain with a less readable `type([])`. Don't override the built-in list to begin with. Name the local variable something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a recursive call only if any item in the current given list is a list; otherwise it means the current list is already the innermost list, so you can return the list as is:

```
def inner_most(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            return inner_most(i)
    return lst

input_list = [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7,[8,9,[10]]]]    
print(inner_most(input_list))
```

This outputs:

```
[10]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SwelteringFlakyDividend

Answer (score -2):

print(list1[-1][-1][-1])

This would get you [10]

Comment: Why not just `print([10])`?